# RxJava: Как в Observable добавить данные в Базу Данных и сразу вывести их в список

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне в пуле Schedulers.io совершить две операции, добавить в бд(это в принципе получилось) и сразу прочить данные с бд и закинуть их в список(список используется для адаптера в recycle view).
В моей реализации я это делаю в mainThread через onNext, тем самым постоянно стопорю главный поток и из-за этого происходят задержки при прокрутке recycle view.
Пытался сделать это через добавление еще одного оператора doOnNext в пуле, но при этом видимо из-за цикла получается какая-то чушь или я что-то недопонял, прощу помощи.

```
public void newsGetRxEnd(List<News> forAdapter, RecyclerView mRecyclerView, Context context) {

    Link link = retrofit.create(Link.class);
        Observable<List<News>> observable = link.endNews(db.getMin("news", "idNews"));

              observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                      .flatMap(urls -> Observable.from(urls))
                .doOnNext(url -> db.addRec(url.getTitle(), url.getId(), url.getSummary(),
                String.valueOf(url.getNewsDate())))
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<News>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        newsAdapterRX(forAdapter, mRecyclerView);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCompleted");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onError " + e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(News news) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onNext");
                        for (int i = forAdapter.size(); i < db.getNewsList().size(); i++) {
                            forAdapter.add(db.getNewsList().get(i));
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"В новом потоке " + db.getNewsList().get(i).getTitle());
                        }

                    }});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение вашего вопроса - это обернуть вашу вставку в Observable, и сделать еще один flatMap. Так же, чтоб это выполнялось только в момент подписки - обернуть в defer() метод.
Что то в таком виде:

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(urls -> Observable.from(urls))
        .flatMap(url -> insertNewsIntoDbObservable(url))

private Observable<News> insertNewsIntoDbObservable(News news){
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(insertToDb(news)));
}

private News insertToDb(News news){
    db.addRec(news.getTitle(), news.getId(), news.getSummary(),
            String.valueOf(news.getNewsDate())));
    return news;
}
```

Метод insertToDb возвращает news для дальнейших операций с ним.

Так же обратите внимание на эти моменты в Вашем методе:

1. А вообще стоит делать вот этот код flatMap(urls -> Observable.from(urls)) ? Не проще ли работать во списком и открыть подключение к базе один раз.
2. Тот же вопрос к этому коду

   ```
   for (int i = forAdapter.size(); i < db.getNewsList().size(); i++) {
           forAdapter.add(db.getNewsList().get(i));
           Log.d(LOG_TAG,"В новом потоке " + 
           db.getNewsList().get(i).getTitle());
    }
   ```

Обращение к базе будет выполняться в Main потоке, что так же будет грузить Ваш UI. У Вас приходит News в onNext, не проще ли брать его с параметра?

3. Рекомендую в реактивном подходе использовать библиотеки, которые поддерживают RX. Например 
   https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio
   https://github.com/square/sqlbrite